# I can't login into freya

Tags: release-freya, greeter

When I try to login to Freya, the screen bounces when I entered the password.

If I go to a console terminal (using CTRL+ALT+F1), I can login OK.
There must be something wrong in my configuration preventing me to login.

I've tried creating a new user and the same thing happens : I can not login.

Any ideas, any one ?

Comment: Did you do anything with your xorg (display) server or something like that? What were your last actions before you were unable to login?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was keyboard configuration.
For some reason, the greeter has been set to US-English keyboard (instead of French) when the console and once logged in Freya is still with the French Keyboard. As the keys are not mapped the same way, I was having an authentication failure.
This was clear when looking at the file:
/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log

I haven't managed to get the French keyboard back (for Greeter) yet but at least I can work around it:
 - I can use the on-screen keyboard (not cool as anybody can see what I am typing ... but it works)
 - I can type the password on the keyboard knowing the US keyboard map (if there's no punctuation signs that's doable).

Hopefully I will manage to get the French keyboard back for the Greeter.

Comment: I managed to switch keyboard by adding a file /etc/default/keyboard with the line :
XKBLAYOUT="fr,us"
I am not able to switch keyboard from the Greeter (I still have the message "no keyboard layout available") ... but I don't care.