# Unable to change keyboard layout in elementary os freya

Tags: release-freya, greeter

I've got an azerty keyboard.

Since I installed Freya, the keyboard in the greeter is in qwerty, and no way to change it. This is really annoying.

It seems that this bug has been encountered since the beginning of Freya, and hasn't be solved. I found several forum threads talking about :

- [fr] http://forum.elementaryos-fr.org/topic/720-clavier-azerty-au-moment-du-login/
- [fr] https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=670561
- [I can't login into freya](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1334/i-cant-login-into-freya?newreg=2db351b078414a0da9c367c559dae3aa)
- [Language changes when I am tying to enter password to login in system](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3415/language-changes-when-i-am-tying-to-enter-password-to-login-in-system)

And none of them gave me a succuessful answer.

My colleague installed Freya some time after me, and he have the same problem.

Things I've done :
- put the whole system in french using system settings

Things I've tried, without any success :

- checked /etc/default/keyboard
- added a section in Xorg conf
- installed lightdm-gtk-greeter (keyboard still in qwerty).

[new]
Installing ubuntu-greeter, I got an azerty login (see my comment on the answer below). So the problem resides in the difference between ubuntu-greeter and pantheon-greeter/lightdm-gtk-greeter.

my /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf :

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "evdev keyboard catchall"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
    # set keyboard to french
    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
    Option "XkbLayout" "fr"
    Option "XkbVariant" "oss"
EndSection
```

my /etc/default/keyboard

```
XKBLAYOUT=fr,us
XKBVARIANT=,oss,
```

(And probably many others I don't remember. But just ask me to try something, and I'll try if you think it can change something)

"Change your password", "use auto-login", or any other such answer will be disregarded; I'm really looking for understanding what's going on, and getting the correct configuration.

At the contrary, any question will be answered, and any :

- reference to some relevant forum/bug
- suggestion for solving this problem,
- indication of which log files can be relevant,
- indication of which source files can be relevant (I can fix and recompile a package if necessary)

, will be welcome.

Comment: can you add specs from your machine? maybe is a drivers problem..

Comment: Thanks for your interest.
What can I tell : its a DELL computer, with a wireless keyboard and mouse.
If you have commands you want me to run, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue. Some people says to re-configure keyboard

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

but i did not work for me until I reconfigure LighDm :

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

Now it works fine for me

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, I've been able to have a correct keyboard layout option switcher by removing `pantheon-greeter` and installing `unity-greeter`
Not as pretty, but a workaround good enough if you really need to be able to switch between keyboard layouts at the login screen ...

Comment: Thanks, it works. Except that the password field text is invisible !?
I retain the idea and will try with other greeters.

Comment: Trying to install lightdm-gtk-greeter doesn't solve the problem : the selected keyboard is "fr_FR", but it's a qwerty configuration.

Comment: (Note that I don't even need to switch between keyboard layouts, just to have the same layout as I always use.)

Comment: Yes password field was invisible, I never found a solution to that as I went back to ubuntu ...

Also if it helps, I saw that the layouts, in my case, was set to the last one I selected during my session. For example, if user A add FR and B had US, selecting A was properly using FR for the login, and B the US ... still messy though.

Answer (score 0):

I used to type my password in qwerty.

As of today, I didn't succeed in login... until I type my password in azerty, and it works !

So, I'm supposing there was a recent upgrade (I don't log in every day - only where there's an upgrade needing a reboot) that solved the problem.